# Custom Walker function need to customize in a specific way for wp_nav_menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have used wp_nav_menu() for my custom WP sites with Custom Walker Function which is working fine and providing me below output:

```
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">    
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">HOME</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="yamm-content">
                            <ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">MY Review Post 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">My Test Post</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But Right now i want to add div class through loop after the ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled" inside the div class "yamm-content". So output will be:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">    
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">HOME</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="yamm-content">
                            <ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">MY Review Post 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">My Test Post</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--------- NEW DIV WILL ADD HERE ----->
                            <div class="imgmenu">
                                <img src="$imageUrl" alt="" />
                                <div class="info">
                                    <h2>title text come here</h2>
                                    <a href="#">learn more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-------- END NEW DIV------>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Please provide some idea how can i get it from my custom Walker function. I just tried to get it through static way but don't know how to place it after ending the `</UL>`. Anybody please help me..

```
class custom_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
private $curItem;

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $thisItem = $this->curItem;

    $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu"><li>
                           <div class="yamm-content">';
            $output .= ( $depth == 0 && $thisItem->object == 'category' ) ? '<ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">' : '<ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled">';


}

//end of the sub menu wrap
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $output .= '</ul></div> </li></ul>';

}

    // add main/sub classes to li's and links
     function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
         $this->curItem = $item;

        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent


        // depth dependent classes
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'dropdown' : '' ),
            (( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' ) ? 'yamm-first' : ''),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // passed classes
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // build html

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // link attributes
        $attributes = ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth == 0 ? 'dropdown-toggle' : '' ) . '"';


        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );


        // build html
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }



    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        if ( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' ) { 

            ?>
                    <div class="imgmenu">
                            <div class="info">
                                <h2>title text come here</h2>
                                <a href="#">learn more</a>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                <?php

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are four functions in the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class which we can customize in our class as explained in the documentation of WordPress itself, [documentation link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) with custom class example.

[Here Excellent explanation on the walker class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039)

1) First function is `start_lvl` called for each level starting which is defined properly in your code and you have wrapped `ul` with `div` class `yamm-content`

2) Second function `start_el` is called for every element starting and it handles generation of `li` and `a` tags which is also defined properly in your code

3) Third function `end_el` is called for ending element and it handles end `li` tag in the core class, you have made mistake here it should be just simple function as core (no need to override it at all)

4) Fourth and last function is `end_lvl` for ending level and you need to apply the code for adding new `div` here `<div class="imgmenu">` which is done in code below:

```
class Test_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    private $curItem;

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $thisItem = $this->curItem;

        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu"><li>
                               <div class="yamm-content">';
                $output .= ( $depth == 0 && $thisItem->object == 'category' ) ? '<ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">' : '<ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled">';


   }

    //end of the sub menu wrap
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            $output .= '</ul>

            <!--------- NEW DIV WILL ADD HERE ----->
                                <div class="imgmenu">
                                    <img src="$imageUrl" alt="" />
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h2>title text come here</h2>
                                        <a href="#">learn more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-------- END NEW DIV------>


            </div> </li></ul>';

    }

    // add main/sub classes to li's and links
     function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
         $this->curItem = $item;

        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent


        // depth dependent classes
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'dropdown' : '' ),
            (( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' ) ? 'yamm-first' : ''),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // passed classes
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // build html

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // link attributes
        $attributes = ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth == 0 ? 'dropdown-toggle' : '' ) . '"';


        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );


        // build html
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }



    /*function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        if ( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' ) { 

            ?>
                    <div class="imgmenu">
                            <div class="info">
                                <h2>title text come here</h2>
                                <a href="#">learn more</a>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                <?php

        }
    }*/
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Dharmang, Really appreciate your support and the answer is might ok when i use in a static way. It works but i need a condition over there which i can not pass. I need that div if this condition `if($thisItem->object == 'category')` follow. But i cannot get the current object value over there. I don't know where i did mistake. But its not working for me :( 
   `

Comment: Hi,
I am little confused, as per your example markup:

    `<div class="yamm-content">
        <ul class="col-sm-12 list-unstyled">....
        </ul>
        <!--------- NEW DIV WILL ADD HERE ----->
        <div class="imgmenu">
            <img src="$imageUrl" alt="" />
            <div class="info">...</div>
        </div>

        <!-------- END NEW DIV------>
    </div>`


I believe you need div class imgmenu after end ul that is end_lvl function and item element have category assigned not the levels.

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).